# Activate iCloud but keep calendar private

Tags: iphone, icloud, calendar, privacy

My company invited me to join its iCloud calendar.

On my iPhone I didn't activate "Calendar" in the iCloud settings until now for data privacy reasons.

Will my private calendar on my iPhone be synced to my personal iCloud as soon as I activate the "Calendar" switch in the iCloud settings? Or does my private local calendar stay local and I'd need to transfer my local calendar to iCloud manually if desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iCloud will automatically sync all calendars not located on another server (such as a Google Calendar). It will take a few minutes to sync all the info to iCloud, then it will be available across all devices. Nothing stays local when iCloud is involved. It goes to the cloud, and syncs when it detects changes.

Comment: Is that true? Then activating iCloud for calendars is no option to me.

Do I have to activate iCloud in order to accept an invitation to an iCloud calendar? Is there any way to accept the invitation but still keeping my other calendars local?

Comment: If the other person has a public link, it could be added to Settings.

Comment: Ok. But in that case it would be a readonly calendar (e.g. like a public bank holiday calendar) so that I cannot update appointments myself.

Comment: What about using a different service for calendars. If you use google services, you can create a calendar that has read & write access.

Comment: Thanks. This in no option in my case as an iCloud calendar already exists which is used by several people.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a seperate "On My Mac" calendar, which stays local. You can then have additional calendars for iCloud—only those calendars will be synced. You don't have to have iCloud activated for calendars to be invited either. Simply create a new "On my Mac" calendar, call it "Work" if you want, and add the event invitations to that.

https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2682?locale=en_US

**Update:**
As mentioned in my comment below. If you have an *existing* local calendar e.g. "On My Mac" or "On My iPad" and you sign into iCloud, you will be asked "What would you like to do with your existing calendars". Click *Cancel* to keep your existing local calendar.

*The local calendar has to exist before signing into iCloud. I couldn't find a way to add a local calendar if already signed into iCloud.*

You will now be able to create a "Work" iCloud calendar and access the shared iCloud calendar. You will also have the private local calendar.

Comment: I want to see the calendar entries of my company in my iPhone on the go i.e. when I'm travelling and a colleague adds an appointment to the iCloud calendar of the company this appointment shall appear in my calendar app on the iPhone. Is that possible?

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2694?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US says: "Invitees to a private calendar must have an iCloud account."

Comment: I did some tests on my iPad-iOS 10.3. I wan't able to add a local calendar while I was signed into iCloud. However, I signed out, created a new "On My iPad" local calendar and created an event. I then signed back in. iCloud asked "What you you like to do with your existing calendars? Merge or Cancel". I Cancelled. I can now see a seperate local calendar on my iPad, that is not available on my other devices. I think this is what you're after? You can now go to Settings > Calendar > Default Calendar to set where your personal events can be saved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I already have a local calendar with lots of private dates. Can I be sure that iOS asks me "What you you like to do with your existing calendars? Merge or Cancel" as soon as I activate iCloud calendar integration. If that's the case that would be a solution indeed.